# Using the for loop function for data scraping

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to learn data scraping and got this far with scraping the horses from the oddschecker site. I'm using Anaconda and Spyder.

I'm currently at the point where the below code gets me an exert with all the info i need:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#create fetchsoup fuction using mozilla
def fetchSoup(url, userAgent='Mozilla/5.0' ):
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': userAgent})
    with urlopen(req) as response:
        html = response.read()
    return BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

#define my url
url = 'https://www.oddschecker.com/horse-racing/chelmsford-city/20:30/top-3-finish'
soup = fetchSoup(url)

#created a new variable, open and close bracket means fuction called and result assigned to the html variable.
html=soup.prettify()

#defined another variable, where we are spliting the above by the flass of diff-row evtabrow bc, which is where the horses are split within the HTML
splitperhorse={'class':'diff-row evTabRow bc'}
#and again
horseinfo=soup.find_all('tr',splitperhorse)
```

--This splits out the data as follows:

```
 horseinfo[0]

 <tr class="diff-row evTabRow bc" data-best-bks="B3,BF,MK" data-best-dig="1.5" data-bid="26459041728" data-bname="Sharney" data-hcap="" data-hcap-sort="1" data-stall="7"><td class="cardnum">9</td><td class="sel nm has-silks basket-active"><span class="float-wrap"><span class="beta-sprite add-to-bet-basket" data-name="Sharney" data-ng-click="MainController.addToMultipleBetSlip(26459041728, 3490400883, 1.5)" data-track="&amp;lid=grid&amp;lpos=basket-add" title="Add Sharney to betslip"></span></span><img alt="Sharney silk" class="silks" height="29" src="https://static.oddschecker.com/content/racing-silks/24372.gif?v=1.0.15" width="39"/><span class="float-wrap name-wrap"><span class="tcell"><div class="top-row"><a class="popup selTxt" data-name="Sharney" href="https://www.oddschecker.com/horse-racing/chelmsford-city/20:30/top-3-finish/bet-history/sharney" target="_blank" title="View odds history for Sharney">Sharney<span class="stall"> (7)</span></a></div><div class="bottom-row jockey"><span class="current-form">0-40</span></div></span></span></td><td class="bc bs oi b" data-bk="B3" data-fodds="1.9" data-hcap="" data-o="1/2" data-odig="1.5"><p>1/2</p></td><td class="bc bs oi" data-bk="SK" data-fodds="2.0" data-hcap="" data-o="2/5" data-odig="1.4"><p>2/5</p></td><td class="bc bs oi" data-bk="LD" data-fodds="1.4" data-hcap="" data-o="4/11" data-odig="1.36"><p>4/11</p></td><td class="bc bs oi" data-bk="WH" data-ew-denom="1" data-ew-places="3" data-fodds="1.83" data-hcap="" data-o="4/11" data-odig="1.36"><p>4/11</p></td><td class="np o" data-bk="EE" data-fodds="" data-hcap="" data-o="" data-odig="0"></td><td class="bc bs oi" data-bk="FB" data-fodds="1.4" data-hcap="" data-o="4/11" data-odig="1.36"><p>4/11</p></td><td class="bc bs oi" data-bk="VC" data-fodds="1.91" data-hcap="" data-o="2/5" data-odig="1.4"><p>2/5</p></td><td class="bc bs oi" data-bk="PP" data-fodds="1.4" data-hcap="" data-o="4/11" data-odig="1.36"><p>4/11</p></td><td class="np o" data-bk="UN" data-fodds="" data-hcap="" data-o="" data-odig="0"></td><td class="bc bs oi" data-bk="CE" data-fodds="1.4" data-hcap="" data-o="4/11" data-odig="1.36"><p>4/11</p></td><td class="bc bs oi" data-bk="FR" data-fodds="1.8" data-hcap="" data-o="4/11" data-odig="1.36"><p>4/11</p></td><td class="bc bs oi" data-bk="WA" data-fodds="1.33" data-hcap="" data-o="2/7" data-odig="1.29"><p>2/7</p></td><td class="bc bs oi" data-bk="SA" data-fodds="1.25" data-hcap="" data-o="2/9" data-odig="1.22"><p>2/9</p></td><td class="bc bs o" data-bk="BY" data-fodds="1.36" data-hcap="" data-o="4/11" data-odig="1.36"><p>4/11</p></td><td class="np o" data-bk="VT" data-fodds="" data-hcap="" data-o="" data-odig="0"></td><td class="bc bs oi" data-bk="OE" data-fodds="1.25" data-hcap="" data-o="2/9" data-odig="1.22"><p>2/9</p></td><td class="np o" data-bk="SO" data-fodds="" data-hcap="" data-o="" data-odig="0"></td><td class="bc bs oi" data-bk="BH" data-fodds="1.25" data-hcap="" data-o="2/9" data-odig="1.22"><p>2/9</p></td><td class="bc bs o" data-bk="GN" data-fodds="1.36" data-hcap="" data-o="4/11" data-odig="1.36"><p>4/11</p></td><td class="bc bs o" data-bk="SX" data-ew-denom="0" data-ew-places="0" data-fodds="1.44" data-hcap="" data-o="4/9" data-odig="1.44"><p>4/9</p></td><td class="np o" data-bk="MR" data-fodds="" data-hcap="" data-o="" data-odig="0"></td><td class="wo wo-col"></td><td class="bc bs oi b" data-bk="BF" data-fodds="1.95" data-hcap="" data-o="8/15" data-odig="1.53" data-x-selection="27351256*1.169809702*horse-racing*29739583*1.169809702"><p>8/15</p></td><td class="np o" data-bk="BD" data-fodds="" data-hcap="" data-o="" data-odig="0"></td><td class="bc bs oo b" data-bk="MK" data-fodds="1.22" data-hcap="" data-o="8/15" data-odig="1.53"><p>8/15</p></td></tr>
```

--what i am trying to do is get into a one horse per row format ie.

Sharney Price1 Price2 Price3 Price4

and then (doesn't matter for now particularly) create a csv to export.

I'm trying to use the for loop function however i am struggling to get to grips with it.

If someone could give me a bit of guidance i would be very much appreciative.

Comment: The URL is not valid, so I'm unable to replicate the data structure from BeautifulSoup. Do you have a different page with the relevant structure?